# Custom screen dimmer

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, screen, brightness

I seek for a night light / f.lux like application, which, roughly speaking, dims bright pixels, but leaves dark pixels nearly unchanged.

More generally, it would be best to have an application that applies some user-defined function / filter over the monitor's output.

If no such application exists, what tools / syscalls are relevant for implementing such a feature?

Comment: You can use `eyesome` available on GitHub under my name

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW; A bash function:

```
function setdbr () 
{ 
    if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        echo "Current displays, numbered:"
        xrandr \
        | sed -nre 's/^([^ ]+ connected.*)$/\1/p' \
        | cat -n
    else
        xrandr --output $(xrandr \
        | sed -nre 's/^([^ ]+) connected.*$/\1/p' \
        | head -n $1 \
        | tail -n 1 ) --brightness $2
    fi
}
```

> setdbr

... shows a numbered list with the displays available

> setdbr n brightness

... adjusts brightness accordingly for display, where:
"n" is one of the numbers from the list, and
"brightness" is to be a 0.0-1.0 value;
  **1.0** is normal,
  **0.5** is 50%,
  Values larger than 1.0 also "work" but looks weird (at least here).